# Check if an S3 key exists without throwing exception

Tags: amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-sdk

In Lambda/.Net Core 2.1, I need to check if an S3 key exists:

```
try
{
    using (var response = await _client.GetObjectAsync(getRequest))
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.ResponseStream))
    using (var sr = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
    {
        existingMods = _jsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Modification>>(sr);
    }
}
catch(AmazonS3Exception e)
{
    if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        existingMods = new List<Modification>();
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

It works, but the problem is that this handled exception is reported in AWS XRay, which is going to be a problem.

Is there a way to check if an S3 key exists without throwing an exception? I saw references to objects in Amazon.S3.IO (e.g. S3DirectionInfo) namespace, but it appears that this namespace is only in Framework 4.5, and I using .NET Core 2.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you use S3FileInfo as in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321625/whats-best-way-to-check-if-a-s3-object-exists

Comment: If I understand it correct, S3FileInfo is not available in .NET Core, only in .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: For what it's worth, the S3FileInfo class is mostly just a wrapper ([Github source](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/S3/Custom/_bcl/IO/S3FileInfo.cs)), so it's possible the exception would have been reported anyway.